# How to return mapping in ton-solidity contracts?

Tags: solidity, everscale

Can I return a mapping in a function of ton-solidity contracts?

I need something like this.

```
function func() public returns((address=>someStruct) myMapping)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Contract.sol**

```
pragma ton-solidity >= 0.51.0;
pragma AbiHeader expire;

struct someStruct {
    string foo;
    uint32 bar;
}

contract Contract {

    mapping (address => someStruct) _myMapping;

    constructor() public
    {
        tvm.accept();
        _myMapping[msg.sender] = someStruct("quz", now);
    }

    function func() external view returns(mapping (address=>someStruct))
    {
        return _myMapping;
    }
}
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit

tondev se reset

rm -fr *.abi.json *.tvc

# Deploy Contract
tondev sol compile Contract.sol
tondev contract deploy Contract --value 1000000000

# Run Contract
tondev contract run-local Contract func
```

**Run**

```
bash run.sh
```

**Result**

```
Execution has finished with result: {
    "output": {
        "value0": {
            "0:0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000": {
                "foo": "quz",
                "bar": "1637140937"
            }
        }
    },
    "out_messages": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
function func() public returns(mapping (address=>someStruct))
```